# How to get detailed Nvidia GPU usage?

Tags: benchmarking, nvidia, nsight, nvidia-smi

Nvidia-smi only provides a few metrics to measure GPU utilization. Most importantly, `utilization.gpu` represents the [percent of time over the past sample period during which **one or more** kernels was executing on the GPU](https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/Useful-nvidia-smi-Queries-2). Thus, it seems that a value of 100% does not at all indicate "full" GPU usage.

Alternatively, [Nsight Compute provides many detailed metrics](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/#metric-collection), but I found it to run very slowly on even small neural networks - it doesn't seem to be the use case. Another option seems to be [DLProf](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/dlprof-user-guide/index.html), but this again only provides rather granular metrics such as "GPU utilization" and "Tensor Core Efficiency", whose definitions I could not find.

Therefore, is there another tool (or parameter) which provides **detailed** GPU usage metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying DCGM?
[https://developer.nvidia.com/dcgm#:~:text=NVIDIA%20Data%20Center%20GPU%20Manager,including%20power%20and%20clock%20management](https://developer.nvidia.com/dcgm#:%7E:text=NVIDIA%20Data%20Center%20GPU%20Manager,including%20power%20and%20clock%20management).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).